# How to write an Open SQL statement with substring in the JOIN ON condition?

Tags: abap, opensql

I am not sure that this is even possible, but I will ask here if somebody smart can help me out.

I have the written the following statement that is obvously not correct, but I would like to have it working in one call to the database if possible.

```
SELECT  po~menge,
        po~vgabe
FROM ekbe as po
JOIN ekbe as dlv ON dlv~ebeln = po~ebeln
                AND dlv~buzei = po~ebelp+1(4)
WHERE dlv~belnr = @nast-objky(10)
  AND dlv~buzei = @nast-objky+12(4)
  AND po~vgabe IN ('1', '8')
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_orders).
```

The wrong part is `po~ebelp+1(4)`.

The problem is that field EBELP is with 5 digits and field BUZEI is with 4 digits.

The solution with 2 separate statements looks like this:

```
    SELECT
       ebeln,
       ebelp
  FROM ekbe
 WHERE belnr = @nast-objky(10)
   AND buzei = @nast-objky+12(4)
  INTO TABLE @DATA(t_po).

  SELECT
         menge,
         vgabe
    FROM ekbe
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @t_po
    WHERE ebeln = @t_po-ebeln
      AND ebelp = @t_po-ebelp
      AND vgabe IN ('1', '8')
    INTO TABLE @DATA(t_orders).
```

EDIT:
this is a wrong question , but the answer from Sandra Rossi would be the correct answer.

My solution is just a correct JOIN:

```
SELECT  po~menge,
        po~vgabe
FROM ekbe as po
JOIN ekbe as dlv ON dlv~ebeln = po~ebeln
                AND dlv~ebelp = po~ebelp
WHERE dlv~belnr = @nast-objky(10)
  AND dlv~buzei = @nast-objky+12(4)
  AND po~vgabe IN ('1', '8')
INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_orders).
```

Comment: What is your ABAP version please?

Comment: Yes, in fact my question is wrong, but if it was correct this is what I would want. Thank very much.